# Create simple array "[x..y]" with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to design some arrays like `[1..25]` in JavaScript, but I don't want to do by hand (`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, [...], 25]`).

How would you do?

Comment: You'll need to iterate one way or another. Using a `for` loop should be simple enough.

Comment: I want to know about the -1: **why?** I don't know there is a `range()` function in another language to be equivalent in JS. If I know how to search for a simple thing like this, I probably didn't create a topic. And another thing: what's wrong with my question? The negatives are because it is "duplicate"?

Comment: Negatives are most likely because you've shown no effort in solving the problem. A simple Google search would lead you to answers.

Comment: @cookiemonster Thank you for clarification, but it's not truth about my effort. I didn't know how to search: what can I do? :<

Comment: For future reference, *"JavaScript create array of numbers"* (without the quotes) gives useful results in Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you could make a simple function...

```
function range(min, max) {
  var len = max - min + 1;
  var arr = new Array(len);
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    arr[i] = min + i;
  }
  return arr;
}

range(1,10);
// [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

This answer is not the smallest amount of code, but it's very readable and tremendously [faster](http://jsperf.com/basic-vs-extreme/3) than any other solution provided here.

Comment: `new Array(len)` can be just `[]`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, it's way faster to set the size of the array if it's known. [See some benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/basic-vs-extreme/3).

Comment: Well if you are into performance than definitely `new Array(len)` is better.

Comment: Are you not into writing well-performing code? For what it's worth, I use `[]` when I'm working with an array of unknown size, but why would you give up tons of speed just to write `[]` instead of `new Array(len)`?

Comment: True, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in shortness, create a small helper function

```
function range(begin, end){
   var arr = [];
   for(var i=begin; i<=end; i++){
       arr.push(i);
   }
   return arr;
}

var myArray = range(1, 25);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the your elements are related (the incrementation is fixed fro instance), you can do this with a loop:

```
for(var i = 1; i<=25; i++) {myArray.push(i);}
```

Comment: that should be a for loop not a while.

Comment: `while` doesn't work that way.

Comment: I know, it was just a mistake by inadvertence

Answer (score 0):

You could add the numbers in a loop eg:

```
var array = [];
for (var i=1; i<26; i++) {
    array[i-1] = i;
}
```

Comment: Just do `var i=1; i<=25` imo

Answer (score 0):

```
var min = 1, max = 25;
Array.apply(null, Array(max - min + 1)).map(function (i,j) {
    return j + min;
});
```

Look ma, no `for` or `while`! Set it into `Array` for convenience: (Using `Array` as namespace)

```
Array.range = function(min, max){
    return this.apply(null, this(max - min + 1)).map(function (i,j) {
        return j + min;
    });
};

Array.range(1, 25);    //[1..25]
```

Comment: A lot of magic at the cost of a lot of [performance](http://jsperf.com/basic-vs-extreme/3).

Comment: @maček - Just for fun. (Because I thought this question is going to be closed for duplicate)